# Plotly, how to subplot pie chart?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, subplot

How can I subplot 'pie1' in 'fig', so it be located at 'the first' position. this is how I am doing it but it doesn't work out:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import plotly.offline as pyp
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly import tools
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.offline import iplot,init_notebook_mode
from IPython.core.display import HTML
import plotly.io

df1=pd.read_excel('file.xlsx',sheet_name='sheet1',index=False)
con_pivot=pd.pivot_table(con,index='Category',values=('Payment'),aggfunc='sum',margins=True,margins_name='Total')

fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2, subplot_titles=('The first','3','2','4'))

pie1=go.Pie(labels=con_pivot.index,values=con_pivot.values,domain=dict(x=[0.5,1.0]),name='Test',hoverinfo='label+percent+name',)
layout = go.Layout(title="Test XXXX",)
data=[pie1]
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
pyp.plot(fig, filename='simple-pie-subplot')
```

I am getting a strange result when I run the script:
[image]

as you can see, it shows only the title. Not sure what I am doing wrong.(I am able to see the chart in chart studio though)

Comment: If you find out i'd be very keen to know. In my research, I haven't seen a way to do that. I've found workarounds with matplotlib.pyplot, but in my research, Plot.ly just won't make a pie chart.

Comment: @Polkaguy6000 do you know how to subplot bars in plotly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to subplot pie chart in plotly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54975791/how-to-subplot-pie-chart-in-plotly)